# MakePackage.exe displaying no output

Tags: bada

I have an project writen in action script. Because I have multiple customers that need essentially the same application but with different assets, I'd like to automate the build process.

I found out that there is a `MakePackage.jar` and `MakePackage.exe` which can be used to repackage my project and can be called through the command line. However, I only get output when I enter incorrect parameters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[See here.](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.documentation.help/html/app_dev_process/packaging_app.htm) Read under "Packaging Applications with the Command Line"

> To build and package your application through the command line:
>
> Run the following commands:
>
> cd \Tools\MakePackage MakePackage.exe TYPE_OPTION
>   PROJECT_PATH
>
> Where PROJECT_PATH is the absolute path of the project to be packaged and TYPE_OPTION is the build configuration to be used:
>
> -td = Target-Debug 
>   -tr = Target-Release  For example, the MakePackage.exe -tr C:\MyWorkspace\MyProject command builds and packages the bada application project stored under C:\MyWorkspace\MyProject with the Target-Release configuration.